# slideId of the master slide in PowerPoint has negative value

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I wrote an AddIn in PowerPoint. When dealing with the master slide, it seems that the slideId has a negative value, and this value leads to the error in my program later. With this negative value, PowerPoint cannot find out the slide according to.

How can I fix them?

I am using PowerPoint 2013, Visual Studio 2013, C#, Windows 8.

Comment: Slides have a SlideID but I see nothing in the documentation or object browser that suggests that a SlideMaster or Design object has this property.  You'll need to find some other way of identifying the master you need.

Comment: How to identify a slide is a master slide or not? And how to identify the master slide? Thanks Steve.

Comment: To give you any sort of useful answer, we'd need more context.  What are you trying to do, exactly?  What code have you already written, where does it error and with what error message?